# How can you generate a list of triangle numbers in python, in a functional manner?

Tags: python, functional-programming

You can generate triangle numbers like this

```
limit = 10
triangle_nums = []
num = 0

for i in range(1, limit + 1):
    num += i
    triangle_nums.append(num)
print(triangle_nums)

output==================
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
```

but is there a better way to do this in a one liner using a more functional approach?

Comment: [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

Comment: Using Gauss' formula: `[i * (i + 1) / 2 for i in range(1, limit + 1)]`

Comment: that works too, but I suppose I really wanted to know a more generalized functional approach for other types of problems, have an upvote

Comment: @Selcuk that's probably worth it's own answer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Obviously the OP is asking for a more generalised solution. I am not sure how generalised it can be though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the built-in [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> limit = 10
>>> list(accumulate(range(1, limit+1)))
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
```

Note, `itertools.accumulate` can take any binary operation, but it defaults to addition,

```
>>> list(accumulate(range(1, limit+1))) # defaults to addition
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
>>> list(accumulate(range(1, limit+1), lambda x,y : x + y)) # you could pass it as an argument
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
but you could use multiplication as an example:


>>> list(accumulate(range(1, limit+1), lambda x, y : x*y))
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]
```

Comment: If you want to use another operator like multiplication, I suggest [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) over a `lambda`

Comment: didn't know that existed. it's just a function that does exactly lambda x, y : x*y right?

Comment: @katiex7 it's just a module that contains function versions of most operators (and a few other convenience functions) for those inclined.